# Working with Dates in Sapui5

Tags: javascript, date, sapui5

How can I get the current date, current year, current month, and current week in sapui5? This is the code I started with:

```
var oType = new sap.ui.model.type.Date();
oType = new sap.ui.model.type.Date({ source: {}, pattern: "MM/dd/yyyy" });
```

I have no idea where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: How do I get the following javascript function into a sapui5 table?

```
function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

function dateFunction() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = addZero(today.getDate());
    var MM = addZero(today.getMonth() + 1);
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var hours = addZero(today.getHours());
    var min = addZero(today.getMinutes());
    var sec = addZero(today.getSeconds());
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'

    today = MM + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy + "  " + hours + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + ampm;
}
```

Comment: You should look at how to get current date in javascript

Comment: Okay. Do you know how I would insert that into a sapui5 table?

Comment: Insert what? To insert anything in a ui5 table you need to add an item to the rows aggregation of table. Can be via binding or addRow.. what is the question exactly?

Comment: How do I call a javascript variable so I can put its value in a sapui5 table? See above edit.

Answer (score 3):

**To get Current Date**:

there is **NO** predefined function in **SAPUI5**, hence use native JavaScript Method:

```
var oDate = new Date();
```

---

**How to put date in a table?**

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vz4k2jt8/)

```
var oData = {
    results: [{
        name: "Today",
        date: new Date()
    }, {
        name: "Someday",
        date: new Date("2015/01/01")
    }, {
        name: "New Year",
        date: new Date("2016/01/01")
    }]
}

var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);


// create table:
var oTable = new sap.m.Table({
    columns: [
    new sap.m.Column({
        header: new sap.m.Label({
            text: "When"
        })
    }),
    new sap.m.Column({
        header: new sap.m.Label({
            text: "Date"
        })
    })]
});
var oType = new sap.ui.model.type.Date({
    pattern: "MM/dd/yyyy"
});
var oTemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
    cells: [
    new sap.m.Text({
        text: "{name}"
    }),
    new sap.m.Text({
        text: {
            path: 'date',
            type: oType
        }
    })]
});

oTable.setModel(oModel);
oTable.bindItems("/results", oTemplate);
oTable.placeAt("content");
```

**Update: Based on comment request**
All you need is this:

```
 var oType = new sap.ui.model.type.Date({
        pattern: "MM/dd/yyyy"
    });
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column("today", {
    label: new sap.m.Label({
        text: {
            path: 'today',
            type: oType
        }
    })
    sortProperty: 'today',
    filterProperty: 'today'
}));
```

Comment: I have created my columns like so:  `oControl = new sap.m.Text({ text: "{today}" });
        oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column("today", {
            label: new sap.m.Label({ text: "today" }),
            template: oControl,
            sortProperty: "today",
            filterProperty: "today"
        }));`  I've gotten it to work with the following format:  Fri Jun 05 2015 09:32:45 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)  How do I get it to work in the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy"  I have tried:  `oControl = new sap.m.Text({ text: { path: '{today}', type: oType } });`  but that didn't work

Comment: I've tried the update. All my data to the right of today gets shifted one column to the left. I think that's because `template` is missing? I added the template but still doesn't format correctly.

Comment: Please add the whole page so that I edit and answer you correctly

Comment: The whole page is about 1000 lines of code. Anyway, I am trying to go with a new approach. See update in original post. Is there anyway I can call dateFunction() in my data? I have tried the following:  `var aData = [{... today: dateFunction() ...}];` but does not work. I don't get an error, it just shows up as an empty cell.